# Android Camera Flickr after "Openned Apps" Button pressed

Tags: android, camera, center, surfaceview

I am trying to develop a camera fragment. I just want to be able to take photos directly in my app,  instead of using the Intent way.

I've achieved this:

[image] [image]

In the left it's all good, just what I wanted. The problem with my code is that, whenever I touch the button highlighted in red in the left image, to check the apps I have in background, and then return to my app, I get the result in the right. As you can see, a black lane (highlighted with a red line) appears.

I don't know why this is happening.

In terms of code, the camera view is offscreen and centered, like the picture below illustrates.

[image]

The camera view is a SurfaceView, which is placed inside a FrameLayout. The camera is centered horizontally in the onLayout method of the FrameLayout.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    int previewBoundaryWidth = right - left;
    int previewBoundaryHeight = bottom - top;

    View cameraPreview  = getChildAt(0);
    if (cameraPreview != null) {
        int widthOverflow = cameraPreview.getWidth() - previewBoundaryWidth;
        widthOverflow = widthOverflow <= 0 ? 0 : widthOverflow;
        int heightOverflow = cameraPreview.getHeight() - previewBoundaryHeight;
        heightOverflow = heightOverflow <= 0 ? 0 : heightOverflow;

        int cameraPreviewLeft = (int) (((float) widthOverflow)/(-2.0f));
        int cameraPreviewRight = cameraPreviewLeft + cameraPreview.getWidth();
        int cameraPreviewTop = (int) (((float) heightOverflow)/(-2.0f));
        int cameraPreviewBottom = cameraPreviewTop + cameraPreview.getHeight();           

        cameraPreview.layout(cameraPreviewLeft,cameraPreviewTop,cameraPreviewRight,cameraPreviewBottom);
    }
}
```

It is clear to me that the black lane that appears corresponds to the shift to the left that is done during the onLayout method over the camera view so that it is centered horizontally. But I don't want that black lane there obviously.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance